# Python-Using Numpy, how to read the data from .txt file and assign the columns of data to variables

Tags: python, database, list, numpy

```
`Time (seconds)           Temp Measured (C)
0.000000000000000000e+00 1.009099999999999966e+02
4.000000000000000000e+00 9.545999999999999375e+01
8.000000000000000000e+00 9.284999999999999432e+01
1.200000000000000000e+01 8.940999999999999659e+01
1.600000000000000000e+01 8.618000000000000682e+01
2.000000000000000000e+01 8.148999999999999488e+01
2.400000000000000000e+01 7.909999999999999432e+01
```

`
is a sample of the long text file and how they are in columns. I am asking how do I read the file and separate these columns when assigning them to variables in one line of python? I keep getting an error whenever i try to convert the .txt to float type

```
p3txt=np.loadtxt("data_.txt")
```

is what i have right now for the file reading

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
a, b = np.loadtxt("data_.txt", skiprows=1).T
```

Explanation:

```
skiprows=1  ->  skip the first row (because it doesn't contain numbers)
.T          ->  take transpose. numpy is [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) meaning that when splitting up the data it will first cut up the columns and leave the rows as whole
a, b        ->  assigning to a tuple of variables triggers the splitting up of the right-hand-side
```

Comment: FYI: Instead of transposing, you can use the argument `unpack=True` :  `a, b = np.loadtxt("data_.txt", skiprows=1, unpack=True)`

Comment: While `unpack` is convenient here, often people try to use it without making sure the load works.  So I think `loadtxt` should first be used without it, and examine the resulting data array.  Is it 2d, is it the right dtype, expected shape, etc.